# a continous map from a topological space to itself is open

Tags: general-topology

I was solving some exercises on general topology and the following question came to mind:

> Let $f$ be a continous map from a topological space $(X,\tau)$ to itself. Is it true that $f$ is an open map?

I tried to prove this but failed. After that, I tried to find some counterexamples but also failed. Is this true?

Comment: $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ from $\mathbb R$ into itself (with usual topology).

Comment: I don't really understand the downvote. It seems a fine question to me.

Answer (score 2):

As @Taladris comments, this is a reasonable question for a beginner who's just heard the general-topology definition/characterization of "continuity", as opposed to the more tangible $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

(And, indeed, there are traditional, understandable confusions in parsing the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, too.)

So, in brief, *no*, continuous maps are mostly not open. They're not necessarily wildly *not* open, but are mostly not open. A mild example is $f(x)=x^2$ on the real line. It *is* open at every point except $x=0$...

Comment: An example of a continuous surjection that is not an open map is $f(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)$ for $x\in\Bbb R$.... This $f$ maps the open interval $ (-1,+1)$ onto the non-open interval $[-2/3\sqrt 3,+2/3\sqrt 3].$